# Entity Framework Core: Contains with Turkish characters

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

**Tech**

- SQL Server 2014 on a shared server with collation `Turkish_CI_AS` - cannot be changed.
- Entity Framework Core 5.0.5

Data in the database:

```
1: MILK THISTLE
2: CLEANSING MILK
3: MILKA CHOCOLATE
```

Query:

```
Products.Where(p => p.Name.Contains("MILK")) // outputs all records
Products.Where(p => p.Name.Contains("milk")) // does not output anything
Products.Where(p => p.Name.Contains("mılk")) // notice the turkish letter ı, outputs all records
```

Desired behavior: search string of either "milk" or "mılk" or "MILK" or "MİLK" should output all three rows.

I tried to use:

- `.ToUpper()`, `.ToLower()` // all combinations you can think of.. runs the same of terms used above.
- `EF.Functions.Like` // runs with no results
- `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` // throws an error
- `EF.Functions.Collate(c.Name, "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS")` // also tried with Turkish_CI_AS runs the same of terms used above

HELP!

---

### EDIT - 2021-06-08

Problem does not seem to be related to only Turkish characters. This query for example:

```
Products.Where(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains("SENSITIVE"))
```

outputs the 10 products of which the word "SENSITIVE" is within their names. However, this query:

```
Products.Where(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains("sensitive"))
```

outputs no results!

Raw SQL string for these queries is:

```
SELECT TOP(@__p_0) [p].[ProductId], [p].[BrandId], [p].[CampaignDisctountAmount], [p].[CampaignMFValue], [p].[Code], [p].[DefaultPicturePath], [p].[Description], [p].[GroupId], [p].[HowToUse], [p].[Ingredients], [p].[InventoryQuantity], [p].[IsDiscontinued], [p].[IsDisplayStockQty], [p].[IsDisplayedOnCatalog], [p].[LogoId], [p].[Name], [p].[Price1], [p].[Price2], [p].[Slug], [p].[Status], [p].[Summary], [p].[Unit], [p].[UnitValue], [p].[VatPercent], [p].[Warnings]
FROM [MED].[Products] AS [p]
WHERE LOWER([p].[Name]) LIKE N'%SENSITIVE%'
```

I run both the SQL strings in SQL Server Management Studio and confirmed that I indeed do not get any results with the word "sensitive" but all matching records are returned when "SENSITIVE" is used.

All names are stored in capital letters in my database. Both the database and the table collation is Turkish_CI_AS and I cannot change that since I am on a shared server.

Comment: Have you tried `EF.Functions.Collate(c.Name, "Turkish_CI_AI")` (notice AI instead of AS at the end). That should make it accent insensitive.

Comment: just tried. no luck.

Comment: Maybe you can use helper method (extension) for search text to convert Turkish char to English. Like this:
                    text = text.Replace("ş", "s").Replace("Ş", "S").Replace(".", "");
                    text = text.Replace("Ğ", "G").Replace("ı", "i").Replace("I", "i");
                    text = text.Replace("ç", "c").Replace("ç", "C").Replace("ö", "o");
                    text = text.Replace("Ö", "O").Replace("ü", "u").Replace("Ü", "U");

Comment: We use something similar to what @GokhanTurkben suggested but its for converting unsupported ANSI characters from unicode to an ANSI equivalent for our collation of choice. To do this we use a table where the key is the character we wish to change from and the value the character we want to use instead. That will allow you to update the characters (or add to them) without needing code changes once you have made the initial change.

Comment: What _exactly_ have you tried with `ToUpper`/`ToLower`? I would expect `Where(p => p.Name.ToUpper().Contains("MILK"))` to work... can you provide the SQL translation? (See LINQPAD.) Also, you should have 4 query outputs since you showed for search strings - what is the fourth result? And what does "no luck" mean when using `Turkish_CI_AI` collation?

Comment: Thank you guys. I came accross to realise the problem might not be related to Turkish characters at all. E.g. this query Products.Where(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains("sensitive")) does not produce any results however Products.Where(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains("SENSITIVE")) actually brings down all products with the word SENSITIVE in it. I am going to go nuts! I will edit my question to include this as well.

Comment: I cannot replace the characters as we do not now if the capital I is intented to be a ' i ' or an ' ı '

Comment: Do any of the names in the database include `'İ'`?  The sample data in the question does not.

Comment: @phoog No.. In fact I deliberately changed cases of letters with different variations to see if it would work but no...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that the comparison is done on the server using the server-side collation, and you can't change that through EF's linq provider (which is why the overload with the `StringComparison` argument fails).  The collation is case-insensitive, but of course, being Turkish, considers `'i'` and '`I`' to be different characters.

The solution is to stop trying to change the case of the product names in the database and instead *modify the search criterion.*

Since none of the data being searched contains `'İ'`, the modification is simple: *call `ToUpper()` on the search value, and make certain that the conversion isn't done with Turkish culture.*  For example, if the default culture *on the client* isn't Turkish, you can just use

```
Products.Where(p => p.Name.Contains("sensitive".ToUpper()))
```

If the client is Turkish, use the overload of `ToUpper()` that takes a `CultureInfo` argument:

```
Products.Where(p => p.Name.Contains("sensitive".ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
```

Come to think of it, the linq provider might actually still do that conversion on the server; if that's the case then you can do the conversion outside the expression lambda:

```
var criterion = "sensitive".ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
return Products.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(criterion));
```

Comment: Product names are automatically imported from the ERP system so I have no control over them. However, .ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) did the trick. Note: ToUpper() did not work. Though it still bothers me that this seems to be more like a trick rather than a complete solution. I accepted it because it works and 'does the job' If tomorrow the client is changed for some reason I'll come here :)

Answer (score 0):

I faced and I handled this problem today. My database is postgreSql and I have some Turkish data. There is not a problem with other Turkish characters like 'ş', 'ç', 'ö', 'ü' and 'ğ' or their  uppercase version.

The problem is in the letter "İ" and the letter "ı". These letters can be in database data or in a searchModel data.

In this case I convert letter "İ" and letter "ı"  into letter "i". Like this:

```
var lowerStr = AnyWordThatContainsTrCharacters.ToLower().Replace("İ", "i").Replace("ı", "i");
return Product.Where(p => p.Name.ToLower().Replace("İ", "i").Replace("ı", "i").Contains(lowerStr));
```